# shutdown ehcache CahceManager in stateless bean

Tags: ehcache

I would like to use ehcache in stateless EJB. As I know if I get a singleton instance of CacheManager then I have to shutdown this instance when I don't need it. However it causes a big overhead for me as a lot of time is needed to create the CacheManager instance if I shutdown it at each call.
Or shouldn't I bother to shutdown the CacheManager in EJB? Won't it cause any issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per EhCache documentation (http://ehcache.org/documentation/operations/shutdown) it's a good practice (and in some case required practice) to shutdown EhCache properly.

Either way, Should be easy to implement: I think you should register a shutdown hook for your EJB (check post [EJB application shutdown hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602706/ejb-application-shutdown-hook)) and in that hook, simply call the CacheManager.shutdown() method.

Hope that helps.